# Google Sheets Java API failing to append values to multiple columns

Tags: java, append, google-sheets-api

I can't find a way to append multiple values to multiple rows, like I do with .update method with the same range value.

```
service.spreadsheets().values()
    .append(
            spreadsheetId,
            "sheet!A2:B300",
            new ValueRange().setValues(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("1", "2")))
    )
    .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").execute();
```

The message I get is:

> "Requested writing within range [sheet!A2], but tried writing to column [B]"

If I use all the same arguments with the .update method instead of .append, everything works nicely.
Also, .append will work if the inner list has only 1 item

-

Thanks

EDIT: I was using HH:mm string as a part of sheet name. It was causing the range error. The same worked on .update method so I didn't consider it important at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append works by finding a table within the requested range and then appending data to the end of that table.  The table it found appears to only have one column (in 'A'), and append is having trouble adding the new column.  You can resolve this by adding a column header in B, most likely.

Admittedly, this isn't super intuitive, so we'll take a look at changing the behavior.

Comment: It's not that. I used the same date string in the sheet name I was using with the update method, but the append method is having troubles with it. I removed the colon from HH:mm and reduced number of characters. It works now

Comment: Oh, weird. You can put a single quote around the sheet name to avoid that. But we'll look into making sure update and append are consistent, too.

Comment: Hitting the same thing. Even with the quotes, colons must be removed or this apparent API bug crops up :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colon from the name of your worksheet, and this apparent bug in the append feature of the Spreadsheet API will go away.